# Conversion of numeric in wal2json

Tags: json, postgresql, apache-kafka, debezium, wal

I have a column **X**, which has datatype `numeric`, in a table.

After streaming changes from PostgreSQL 10 to Kafka using debezium together with the logical decoding plugin, wal2json; I read the json output with a `Java` Kafka Consumer. I noticed that the `numeric` data from column **X** has been converted to `String`.

Example:- the `numeric` below (from table):

```
"column X" = 1675.32
```

becomes a `String` (json in Kafka):

```
"column X": "Ao5s"
```

Any idea why it did not remain a `numeric` as compared to other datatypes?

Furthermore, is there any way to convert this `String` back to `numeric`, as there is no indication about datatype conversion in wal2json from this [github link](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) and [blog](http://eulerto.blogspot.com/2018/03/wal2json-10-released.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please check `decimal.handling.mode` for discussion about precise decimal number datatypes and their representations.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, but thanks for answering. I will have a look at it.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it sure did help me as originally, I thought that wal2json was responsible for that. So, the default configuration property is then set to `string`, not `double`? How come?

Comment: Defualt is precise that encodes the value as `BigDecimal`. The reason is the loss of precission when precise numeric value is converted to floating point representation.
Generally for Java clients you should you use default setting and decode it using https://debezium.io/docs/faq/#how_to_retrieve_decimal_field_from_binary_representation
For non-Java clients the string setting is the best.
If you don't care about precision then switch it to double.

Comment: Ok, had to manually add its configuration property to change that. Sure, I would rather go for precision instead. Really appreciate your kind help sir.

Comment: Additional note: Surprisingly though, the default was set to `string`, not `precise`.